# Minecraft on several computers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I have two computers. Minecraft is on both of them, and I am logged in with the same account on both. Say I went on one computer, mined some items on a server, and logged out. If I went on the same server with the other computer would I have those items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Inventory on Minecraft servers is stored based on account, not connection.

Note that for single-player you would have to locate and move the (single-player) save files between the two computers to have a persistent world and inventory within it.